# Evaluating the sum $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(3k+1)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am looking for a closed form to: $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(3k+1)^2} $

Comment: [Apparently](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum++1+%2F+%283k+%2B+1%29^2+from+k+%3D0+to+infinity), it's $$\frac{\psi^{(1)}(1/3)}{9}$$ with $\psi$ the digamma function.

Comment: So *that's* how you use Wolfram Alpha!  I know very little about this function.

Answer (score 2):

Straight from the definition of [a trigamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigamma_function)
$$ \psi_1(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(z + n)^2},$$
So $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(3k+1)^2}=\frac{1}{9}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\left(k+\frac{1}{3}\right)^2}=\frac{1}{9}\psi_1\left(\frac{1}{3}\right) $$

Comment: You can also express this sum as 1/9 PolyGamma[1, 1/3] or 1/9 LerchPhi[1, 2, 1/3] or 1/9 Zeta[2, 1/3]. All these functions are elated to eachother.